# How do I execute a method from within a vue.js component

Tags: vue.js, nested-function

I would like to call function `b` from inside function `a` in a vue.js component

This is the code I have

```
   methods:{
      a(){ 
            console.log("a")
            b();
       }
      b(){
           console.log("b")
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by adding `this` before your function: `this.yourFunction`

```
export default{
    data(){
        return{
            data1: 1,
            data2: 1
        }
    },
    methods:{
        a(){
            if(this.data1 == this.data2){
                this.b(); //call b() function
            }
        },
        b(){
            //do something
        },
    }
}
```

you can also do the same to use your `data()` variables

Comment: you can also do the same to use your data() variables --means? can u please provide eg

Comment: inside the `if`, I used `data1` and `data2`

Answer (score 0):

Use this it will solve the problem.

```
 methods:{
  a(){ 
        console.log("a")
        this.b();
   }
  b(){
       console.log("b")
   }
}
```

If you want to call it outside the method use this.method()

[Documentation reference](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/events.html#Method-Handler)

Comment: i just meant outside methods not outside the export or vue :)

Comment: ya u can doesnt matter if  not marked just keeping posting it will help some or the other:)